# How to calculate $ \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^n}{n!}}$

Tags: summation, exponentiation

I am solving for the stationary distribution whose state space is $S = ${$0, 1, 2,....$}. I need to calculate $ \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^n}{n!}}$ for $ π(0)$.
Then answer is $e^{-3}$, but I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}.
$$